# How to represent repeatitive String in Java

Tags: java, string, class, repeat

I have a Java class called the "Sub_class". It is basically used to store a set of String variables that are used as inputs in another Java class called the "Main_class". The Sub_class looks something like this :

```
package mdoel;
public class Sub_class{

    String model_name= "Model_102";
    String Output_shortname= "MyOutput";

    String Value_1= "C:\\Hello\\Folder\\One.pdf";
    String Value_2 ="C:\\Hello\\Folder\\Two.pdf";
    String Value_3 ="C:\\Hello\\Folder\\Three.pdf";
}
```

Here instead of using the same repetitive string ("C:\Hello\Folder") I thought of assigning this to another variable called standard so that I do not have to repeat the whole string and use this variable in palce of it. For example something like this:

```
package mdoel;
public class Sub_class{

    String standard = "C:\\Hello\\Folder";
    String model_name= "Model_102";
    String Output_shortname= "MyOutput";

    String Value_1 = standard\\One.pdf;
    String Value_2 = standard\\Two.pdf;
    String Value_3 = standard\\Three.pdf;
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. I basically want to try and reduce the code here. Could somebody please tell me how could I approach this.I am sorry if I have made it sound confusing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like :

```
String Value_1 = standard+ "\\One.pdf";
```

The String field should not be in quotes, the String being appended / added should be.

Comment: You should use File.Separator instead of hard coding the slashes.

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob - Yes, that's right. Reading the platform's file separator and then using it would be a good idea

Comment: I think it would be great to have that included in your answer. People tends to adapt with the shortcut if it is represented.